# Submit button too large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

i play around with Ruby on Rails in combination with Bootstrap.
What i have done is a form for contact.

**My problem is** when i create the form with ruby-syntax like:

```
<%= form_for @contact, html: {role: "form"} do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :message %>
    <%= f.text_field :message, :class => "form-control" %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

then the submit-button gets very large (100% of the page).
In the custom Bootstrap they take the button-tag and not the submit-tag.

Is their any possibility to implement a button-tag in Ruby on Rails as a submit-button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is their any possibility to implement a button-tag in Ruby on Rails as
>   a submit-button?

There is a `button_tag` for you.It just as like a `HTML submit button`.

```
<%= button_tag "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

#=><button name="button" type="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

For more details, see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag)**

Ofcourse,you can do it like this too

```
<%= f.button "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved it like this:
`<%= f.button "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>`